# How to center Logo in responsive website

Tags: html, css, centering, responsive

if you go to our site [HERE](http://142.4.207.71/) in Firefox and view in responsive mode at 769 width, you will notice the logo is not truly centered at the top. I am wondering how i can achieve true centering of the logo. You can tell it is shifted to the right a little.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:
in (responsive.css) file line number 129 replace this css and your logo will be center.

```
.header > .logo {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -125px !important;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the logo image to display as block and apply auto margins. This allows you to use different size logos depending on your display and the logo will always be in center.

Use this property:
{ display:block; margin: 10px auto; }